# Opengl glRotatef rotating a polygon, won't rotate in place

Tags: opengl, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a polygon in place, but it keeps revolving instead.

To rotate, I calculate the center by finding the average location of each vertex. I call the rotation functions and then call a translation using the center to move it to the middle of the screen. It does end up centered, but it still rotates as if it's not. Any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
void Polygon::DrawPolygon()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadMatrixf(matrix);
    glTranslatef(displace[0], displace[1], displace[2]);
    glRotatef(rotation[0], 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(rotation[1], 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(rotation[2], 0, 0, 1);
    glTranslatef(-displace[0], -displace[1], displace[2]);
    displace[0] = 0; displace[1] = 0; displace[2] = 0;
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix);
    DrawMaterial();
    DrawFaces();
    ConnectFaces();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Here's how I calculate the center:

```
void Polygon::FindCenter()
{
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float z = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        for(int i =  0; i < vertexCount; i++)
        {
            x += vertices[i][0];
            y += vertices[i][1];
            z += vertices[i][2] + extrusionDistance * j;
        }
    }
    x = x / (vertexCount * 2);
    y = y / (vertexCount * 2);
    z = z / (vertexCount * 2);

    displace[0] = x;
    displace[1] = y;
    displace[2] = z;
}
```

Because of the way my extrusion works I don't need to add the x and y for the vertices of both faces, but I did anyway to keep it consistent.

Here is how I draw the shape:

```
void Polygon::DrawFaces()
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        for(int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
        {
             glVertex3f(vertices[i][0], vertices[i][1], j*extrusionDistance);
        }
        glEnd();
    }
}

void Polygon::ConnectFaces()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
    {
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex3f(vertices[i][0], vertices[i][1], 0);
        glVertex3f(vertices[i][0], vertices[i][1], extrusionDistance);
        glVertex3f(vertices[(i+1)%vertexCount][0], vertices[(i+1)%vertexCount][1], extrusionDistance);
        glVertex3f(vertices[(i+1)%vertexCount][0], vertices[(i+1)%vertexCount][1], 0);
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you intend to leave out `displace[2]` in the second translate? Can you show how you calculate the displace values?

Comment: I think that might've done it. I use a for loop to go through each vertex and sum them together. But what I'm doing is drawing a polygon based on user input and then extruding it. I'll edit to show what I think is working and include how I calculate displace.

Comment: Looked like it was working, but it's having the same issue. I still don't get why.

Comment: If I use the exact same rotation with glutSolidTeapot(1); it works as I'd expect it to. When I draw the polygons instead it doesn't at all. I'll include how I draw the polygons, but is there any chance that's what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things that stand out to me as being odd:

1) You're calling `glLoadMatrixf(matrix)` before the call to `glTranslate()` and `glRotate()`. Depending on what's in the matrix you're loading, that changes things.

2) You're `FindCenter()` method calculates the center by including the `vertex[i][2]` in the calculation of z, but when you actually draw the faces in `DrawFaces()`, you don't include the `vertex[i][2]` part, just the `extrusion * j` part. So you're not drawing the same thing that you're calculating the center of.

Comment: The matrix I'm loading is the one that's saved at the end with glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix);. I know that part's not the problem. What I'm doing is rotating the polygon by using a mouse input, and I don't want the rotation to reset every time the user clicks, so I save the matrix to record the rotation.

EDIT: I shouldn't say I *know* it works. I used it before for rotating a few solid teapot models and it worked perfectly. I'd be surprised if that's where the problem lies.

Comment: As for your second comment, that's a good catch and a poor way to code it on my part. But the way the faces are drawn is the user clicks to add vertices and then right clicks to extrude. So the first face is being drawn at z = 0. For this project I always pass 0 as the value for vertices[i][2] regardless of what i is.